# System programming on C

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, system

I want to try to develop system software, drivers for devices. I know that C is low level programming language and it is very popular in this scope.
What compiler is better to use (only C, not C++)? and what libraries are used for system related stuff? 
OS Windows.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you're basically stuck using Visual C++. I don't think MS produces a dedicated C compiler.

Comment: Well, you presumably could use any C compiler that targets Windows.

Comment: WDK (formerly DDK) is what you need, but are you sure you want to start with driver development? Without decent programming knowledge in that area it's like playing with grenades. I would make first steps in C in user space and then move to driver development which is another level of difficulty especially in a microkernel architecture you have to master IRPs and IRQ levels very well otherwise you'll face a blue screen after the other...

Answer (score 2):

If you wan to do Windows driver development, then you should look at the [WDK - Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/default.mspx). It should have most of what you need including tools, headers and libraries (and documentation).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows look at the WDK and related MSDN documentation.  The WDK includes Microsoft's compiler.  http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx

There is a lot to absorb there.  If you're new to programming you should get some experience with C at the user application level and then try out Kernel development once you are comfortable with the language.